# TYPO3 logout after window resize

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 7.6.18 and I have next problem: when I choose in browser console mobile mode - it logout FE user on my typo3 site. Why it happens ?

Comment: Which browser? Which version?

Comment: By the way, use always the latest version of TYPO3 to be sure that a possible bug isn't resolved yet.

Comment: Chrome browser I use

Comment: I checked it in firefox - there it works properly without logout

Comment: Did you try it with TYPO3 7.6.21?

Comment: no thanks I will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the resizing but switching the user agent which is done if you e.g. select an Iphone. Until 8.7 (see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/8.7/Changelog/8.6/Breaking-79513-RemovedSessionLockingBasedOnUseragent.html) the useragent was checked as well for a valid login.

Possible solutions:

- Remove the keyword "useragent" from the configuration in the Install Tool
- Update to 8.7

Comment: I set useragent field as empty. But when I toggle mobile/desktop mode in chrome it still logout me